# jQuery mousemove to hide a navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events, mousemove

I'm using a simple JS event to show/ hide navbar's element and it doesn't work:

```
$('.menu ul li ul').hide();


if($(window).width() > 1000){
    
    $('.menu ul li').bind('mousemove', function(){
        
        $('this').children('ul').fadeIn();
    })
    
    $('.menu ul li').bind('mouseleave', function(){
        
        $('this').children('ul').fadeOut();
    })
}
```

Comment: Check if javascript is enabled in your browser

Comment: Check `($(window).width()`

Comment: $('this') is wrong! You need to write $(this) without any single quote. Also make sure that the window's width is at least 1000 pixels, or else, those events won't bind...

Comment: thank you for your reply but actually it's set as `true` (firefox) and still doesn't work :/

Comment: How is "_however it works when tested on someone else'computer_" even possible? The code definitely "doesn't work" on any machine. Also, some [interesting reading](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.0/).

Comment: thank you Mehdi and all of you guys :D yeah it was because of the $('this') (I made an error when I copied the code from the other computer I'm so dumb xD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved:

syntax error by writing `$('this')` instead of `$(this)` as Mehdi said in his comment.

updated code:

```
$('.menu ul li ul').hide();

if($(window).width() > 1000){

$('.menu ul li').bind('mousemove', function(){

    $(this).children('ul').fadeIn();
})

$('.menu ul li').bind('mouseleave', function(){

    $(this).children('ul').fadeOut();
 })
}
```